# Shortcut for opening the definition file in a split vertical group in vscode

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

Are there any shortcuts to open the definition (e.g.: a method definition) in a split vertical group? By <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> on the usage of method, it opens in a new tab. It bothers me, because I have to leave my own tab.

(I know that after opening in a new tab, by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> it will be open it in a new group, but this also has the same problem: I lose my own tab, and a second problem: when I want to close the definition file, I have to close it from both the 2nd group and the 1st group.)

Are there any shortcuts to open the definition file directly in a new group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> seems to open the definiton file in a split editor.

It'll open to whatever you have this setting:

`Workbench > Editor: Open Side By Side Direction` // options are right and down

---

Note that it'll directly open the definiton file in a split editor only if there is a single possible defintion file.  For example, you may have both a source and a dist folder with the same files in them (after some task runner commands perhaps).  If there is more than one option, vscode will instead open a peek window with the multiple references listed to the right side.  You can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on whichever of those you want to open to the side.