# how to rebind "alt + control + click" open definition to a keyboard short cut in vs code

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

Trying to create a keyboard shortcut that will allow me to remap alt+ Cntrl + click to a keyboard only shortcut because I can get the previous sequence to open the definition in the split tab, whereas the regular f12 keybinding only opens it in the current split pane. For some reason, I cannot see where to rebind the alt + Cntrl + click binding. The reason being im trying to ilmit my mouse usage as im using vim commands.

The "alt + control + click" was found from this answer and describes that it opens in a new tab, but how to change the click to a keyboard keystroke is the question: [Shortcut for opening the definition file in a split vertical group in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213774/shortcut-for-opening-the-definition-file-in-a-split-vertical-group-in-vscode)

Comment: Perhaps asking in a VS thread rather than vim may get better answers?

Comment: I have vscode tags, im not even sure where to see if im in a vim thread?